# LInking to CSS from Module CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, module

So I have a module setup and working, and have setup an asset folder within it containing a css and js folder. My files are in there, but when I try linking to them like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src=/application/modules/badge_progress/assets/js/jquery.jcarousel.js"></script>
```

Or this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src=<?php echo base_url(); ?>/application/modules/badge_progress/assets/js/jquery.jcarousel.js"></script>
```

They don't work. What is the proper way to link to the files?

Answer (score 0):

You cant access directly from /application folder from web browser. 
Move `badge_progress` folder with same directory with application and try this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<? echo base_url();?>badge_progress/assets/js/jquery.jcarousel.js"></script>
```

Comment: Well the badge_progress needs to stay within the modules folder. I am trying to make the modules completely separate from the rest of the application, including all of their assets within their own module folder. How do I do this?

Comment: well than make **modules** folder with same directory with application and make js, css and etc there. You shouldnt put any of them in application folder. CI dont allow access directly from browser

Comment: But the modules folder needs to be in the application folder to run, I'm pretty sure...

Comment: i am tring to say Codeingiter dont allow to access application folder for security issue. Its not hard make another folder outside.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with your quotation marks. The `src` value starts with no quotation mark but ends with one.  Try

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>/application/modules/badge_progress/assets/js/jquery.jcarousel.js"></script>`
```

Comment: This was my solution:
I moved the 'modules' folder outside the application folder, and then, because I am using HMVC, I went into the config file, and put this at the bottom:

    // instead of 'modules' put '../modules'
    $modules_location = '../modules';
    
    // don't need to touch :)
    $config['modules_locations'] = array(APPPATH . $modules_location .'/' => '../'.$modules_location.'/'); 

This changed the path to my modules folder so I could move it outside of the application folder.

Thanks everyone for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

keep your js and css file in root folder and try and check in firebug js file and css file is loading or not and what path is created for that file and then fix it.